# Academic Resources for Torah & Talmud Study

Tags: product-recommendation, torah-study

I am looking for specific online resources or fundamental books and guides (online or in print) that are practical and helpful tools for a more 'academic' approach to the study of Tanakh and Talmud. Any suggestions? Are there any existing lists?

To clarify, by 'academic' I mean an intellectual approach that values methodology and philosophy, the historical and literary context, intertextuality and grammar, and is open to non-Rabbinic scholarship. Not the typical traditional Yeshiva model of learning.

Some examples include Jastrow's Dictionary, [Sefaria](https://www.sefaria.org/?home), [AlHatorah's Concordance](https://mg.alhatorah.org/Concordance_Guide), [JStor](https://www.jstor.org/)/[Project Muse](https://muse.jhu.edu/) or [theTorah.com](https://www.thetorah.com/)

Comment: https://dev.clariah.nl/files/dh2019/boa/0229.html#_ga=2.109706892.86961552.1618237944-795933420.1616703201

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/This-Very-Day-Fundamental-Questions/dp/1592645151

Comment: Can you explain what an 'academic' approach is and what isnt

Comment: @interested Will clarify above in the OP

Comment: If Sefaria qualifies, don't literally any Jewish book qualifies? I find it difficult to understand what is in scope for your question vs. not. Unless you clarify, I am afraid your question might get closed.

Comment: @mbloch I don't agree. Sefaria's features such as its dictionary, translations, #topics and relevant manuscripts make it a particularly helpful tool. Embedded into the sections of text are fantastic source sheets and webpages that look at things from a more academic perspective. The layout interface and wide range of pirushim and sefarim make it a very practical tool for conducting a comparative analysis and it also boasts modern academic commentaries alongside the classic rabbinic commentators. All in all it makes for a very valuable academic resource.

Comment: If what you mean is like decision tree approach to learning which I consider the correct way i can name you a sefer on the otsar which does that for the MB

Comment: I don't think you need non-Rabbinic works, just pre-Brisker works that deal with those issues. Yaavetz, Maharatz Chayos, etc.

Answer (score 1):

In my search for an answer I came across Rabbi Anthony Manning's list of suggested On-Line Web Resources (almost 400 sites). Some of these links fit the bill.

https://rabbimanning.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/On-Line-Web-Resources-2017-Version-3-March-2017.pdf

This led me to his homepage which has a Recommended Reading tab which consists of 180 books and works Rabbi Manning suggests to intelligent individuals "interested in seeing a range of perspectives and approaches... who are looking for a guide to how to continue their Jewish reading and learning once they leave the ‘bubble’ of Yeshiva/Seminary life."

https://rabbimanning.com/index.php/links/recommended-reading/

Answer (score 0):

The Jewish Study Bible comes to mind: [https://www.amazon.com/Jewish-Study-Bible-Second/dp/0199978468](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0199978468)